# Why is my equation returning wrong response

Tags: php

I have an if statement that is supposed to determine whether the value entered by the user is less than 30% of their salary

```
if($amount + $interest/100 * $amount > 30/100* $employee['net_salary']){
        exit(
            json_encode([
                'is_error'=> true,
                'message'=> 'Amount requested is to high'
            ])
        );
    }
```

Whatever the value I enter I will get the error message

Comment: you should wrap things in brackets...

Comment: You must learn about operator precedence, so you will get the solution by yourself

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code https://3v4l.org/UEV0f

Comment: @treyBake the code is fine as is.

Comment: @AnkurTiwari the code is fine as is.

Comment: Yes @Nick, it is just a suggestion to learn operator precedence.

Comment: _Suggestion:_ Define two variables where you calculate the values. Then check if those values get the correct result. When that's done, use those variables in your if-statement, Example: `$foo = a + b; $bar = c + d; if ($foo > $bar)` but with variable names that are descriptive. That will make your code _much_ easier to read and debug since you can dump the variables to see if they are correct.

Comment: Yeah but the operator precedence is *perfectly fine* for what OP wants to do.

Comment: @Nick yes I have seen your example that you have share

Comment: @Nick that depends on expected value... the code is fine, it's the maths I'm on about, currently it does (using placeholder numbers for example): `(30/100*20)+20 > (30/100)*10000`

Comment: @treyBake which to me matches the problem description 'value entered by the user is less than 30% of their salary' (once some interest has been added) since if the test is true a 'value too high' message is generated.

Comment: @Nick maybe, but personally I need OP clarification to make sure^ probably right, but I like to be pedantic and any excuse to bust out a bracket

Comment: @treyBake :-) now I guess it's probably time for me to move on...

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
if(($amount + (($interest/100) * $amount)) > ((30/100) * ($employee['net_salary']))){
        exit(
            json_encode([
                'is_error'=> true,
                'message'=> 'Amount requested is to high'
            ])
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the code. Be sure to wrap things in brackets whenever nessicary.

Try this code instead.

```
if(($amount + (($interest/100) * $amount)) > ((30/100) * ($employee['net_salary']))){
    exit(
        json_encode([
            'is_error'=> true,
            'message'=> 'Amount requested is to high'
        ])
    );
}
```

Comment: Since there's nothing wrong with the code, there's no reason to wrap anything in parentheses.

Comment: You start by saying _"Nothing wrong with the code"_ and then asking the OP to try your code instead? Why? If there's nothing wrong with the code, why should they change it?